# Limit number of entries for a Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I limit the quantity of entries for a specific form? For example, I only need 20 registers. After that the form should no longer accepting new submissions.

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the total number of submitted entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) by setting [quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/quantity-limits) on your form:

1. Add a *Calculation* field to the bottom of your form
2. Set **Calculation** to *Registration*
3. Set **Quantity Limits** to *Specific Quantity*
4. Set **Quantity** to *20*
5. Set **Error Message** to *Registration is full!*
6. Set **Show This Field** to *Never*

This will limit the total number of submitted registrations and show an error message to anyone trying to view/submit the form once registration is full.  If you later delete a registration, this will automatically open up registration slots.

[image]